# I need to extract data from an XML document

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

Hi I'm having trouble extracting data from this XML document.

```
  <messages messageCount="6">
  <message messageID="9999" orderNumber="1234" model="TESTMODEL" val="490" status="8" timestamp="2012-07-12 13:12:50Z">
  <attributes>
  <attribute name="ATT1" value="1234" /> 
  <attribute name="ATT2" value="5678" /> 
  </attributes>
  </message>
  </messages>
```

I need to recursively loop through each message and get the values of the message node.  I then need to loop through the attributes and get the value of the attribute nodes if the status is a certain value.  I'm having a bit of trouble.  So far I have this

```
        Dim strStream As New MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strMessage))

        Dim XmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument

        XmlDoc.Load(strStream)


        Dim nlNodeList As XmlNodeList = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("//messages/message")
        Dim a As XmlAttribute

        For Each nNode As XmlNode In nlNodeList
            Dim strmessageID As String = String.Empty
            For Each a In nNode.Attributes
                If a.Name = "messageID" Then
                    strmessageID = a.Value
                End If
            Next
            For Each nChildNode As XmlNode In nNode.ChildNodes
                For Each b In nChildNode.ChildNodes
                    For Each a In b.Attributes
                        If a.Name = "ATT1" Then

                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

but i'm having trouble getting the attribute values.  I'm sure there must be a cleaner way of doing this too.  I was previously using Datasets and was fine until I tried to get to the attributes values

```
    For Each dr As DataRow In dsmyDS.Tables("message").Rows
        Dim strMessageID As String = dr.Item("messageid").ToString
        Select Case CStr(dr.Item("model").ToString)
            Case "TESTMODEL"
                Select Case dr.Item("status").ToString
                    Case "8"
                        Dim strval As String = dr.Item("val").ToString
                        'Don't know how to get at the attributes node list once I'm here
                    Case Else

                End Select
            Case Else

        End Select
    Next
```

It would great if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.  Which is the best method to use?  XMLDocument or a Dataset?  Is there an easier way then my longwinded method?

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: I think you are getting confused between attributes, and elements whose name is "attribute"; and you are also getting confused between the name of an element, and the value of the attribute of an element whose name is "Name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `LINQ-XML` Import the System.Data.Xml.

```
 Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(file)
'Or
'Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(strMessage)
 Dim Result = doc.Root.Descendants("message")
                      .Where(Function(p)
                                Return p.Attribute("status").Value = "8"
                             End Function)
 For Each ele In Result
     MsgBox(ele.Attribute("messageID").Value)
     MsgBox(ele.Element("attributes").Element("attribute").Attribute("name").Value)

     'List children of attributes tag
     For Each v In ele.Element("attributes").Elements()
          MsgBox(v.Attribute("name").Value & " " & v.Attribute("value").Value)
     Next
 Next
```

Comment: Hi AVD.  I'm passing in a stream instead of a file and get the error "Root element is missing." when I get to XDocument.Load.

Comment: You have to import `System.Xml.Linq` and Use `XDocument.Parse(stringXml)` to load xmlstring.

Comment: You, kind sir, are a legend.  Thanks so much!  I Really need to brush up on my XML skills!

Comment: One last question.  The example you gave will only give the top attribute.  In my example "ATT1".  How do I loop through the attributes node list for each "ele".  Or how do I just select the attribute whose name matches a certain string, and return the value of that attribute?

Comment: I Changed your code to search just for the child node I was looking for using a combination of both your examples.  Don't know how to post code in the comments but I used <br/>

`For Each v In ele.Element("attributes").Elements().Where(Function(s)`<br/>
`Return s.Attribute("name").Value = "OTDAT" `     <br/>                                                                   `End Function)`